# How to calculate average without outlier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate average without outliers(with in 2 standard deviation). I keep getting error message "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
  select
  b.[Location],  

  b.[txtOrderSubType],

  avg (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate])) as 
 [Avg Duration in min],


 from dbo.tbl1
 Where        
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate])< ( 
  AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate]))+
  2*STDEVP(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate])))

 and  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate])> ( 
      AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate]))- 
      2*STDEVP(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.[dteActualStartDate], b.[dteActualEndDate])))

  group by b.[Location], b.[txtOrderSubType]
```

Answer (score 0):

On one level, the question doesn't make sense, because the average changes.  Although I'll answer this question, you might want some other definition of outlier.

```
select avg(al)
from (select t.*, avg(val) over () as avg_val, stdev(val) over () as stdev_val
      from t
     ) t
where val between avg_val - 2 * stdev_val and avg_val + 2 * stdev_val;
```

I have no idea how this fits into your query, which seems needlessly complicated.